# error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when testing with JEST in the react native cli environment

Tags: react-native

Native cli environment was built and third-party libraries were introduced.
The testing environment was left unchanged as default.

After that, I ran jest, but I get an error. I can't solve it.
Please help.

**tests**/App.test.tsx

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../src/App';

// Note: import explicitly to use the types shiped with jest.
import {it} from '@jest/globals';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

Here are the results
% yarn jest

```
__tests__/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:


    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    1 | import {config} from '@**';
```

I have tried the steps in the following document.
https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript